# Extract the rows based on the specific values in the column by time

Tags: r, time, rows, data-extraction

I have a data frame looks like :

| Date | v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000/8/10 | S | 2600 |
| 2000/8/10 | S | 500 |
| 2000/8/10 | S | 3500 |
| 2001/11/12 | B | 2000 |
| 2001/11/22 | B | 1000 |
| 2001/11/22 | S | 1000 |
| 2001/12/06 | B | 1000 |
| 2001/12/06 | B | 1500 |
| 2001/12/06 | B | 1000 |
| 2001/12/07 | S | 2000 |
| 2001/12/07 | B | 4000 |

However, I'd like to extract the rows which has "B" and "S" in the same date
It looks as below :

| Date | v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001/11/22 | B | 1000 |
| 2001/11/22 | S | 1000 |
| 2001/12/07 | S | 2000 |
| 2001/12/07 | B | 4000 |

Does anyone have ideas? That would be grateful !
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `Date` which has both `'S'` and `'B'` in them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(all(c('S', 'B') %in% v1)) %>%
  ungroup

#  Date       v1       v2
#  <chr>      <chr> <int>
#1 2001/11/22 B      1000
#2 2001/11/22 S      1000
#3 2001/12/07 S      2000
#4 2001/12/07 B      4000
```

This logic can also be implemented in base R and `data.table` :

```
#Base R
subset(df, as.logical(ave(v1, Date, FUN = function(x) all(c('S', 'B') %in% x))))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(c('S', 'B') %in% v1)], Date]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2000/8/10", "2000/8/10", "2000/8/10", 
"2001/11/12", "2001/11/22", "2001/11/22", "2001/12/06", "2001/12/06", 
"2001/12/06", "2001/12/07", "2001/12/07"), v1 = c("S", "S", "S", 
"B", "B", "S", "B", "B", "B", "S", "B"), v2 = c(2600L, 500L, 
3500L, 2000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1500L, 1000L, 2000L, 4000L
)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```